# Cyclic shift of numbers in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, shift

I need to perform a cyclic shift of the array elements to the left by n characters.

**Here is my code:**

```
    public static void moveLeft(int[] arr, int num) {
    int[] temp = new int[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }

    for(int i = arr.length - num; i > 0; i++) {
        arr[i-num] = arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }
}
```

When I run this code, **I get this error**: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10

Comment: Your second loop runs while `i > 0` and has `i++` as the update. One of those is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for( ...; i > 0; i++)` is very suspicious, that is, while `i > 0` do increment `i` (if not starting with negative values, `i` will be incremented till it (silently) overflows or an Exception is thrown somewhere else).

{incrementing `++` requires an upper limit `< value` (or `<=`); decrementing `--` a lower one `> value` (or `>=`) }

The code is accessing `arr[i]` (and `arr[i-num]`), so `arr.length` should be the limit (assuming non-negative `num`): `i < arr.length`
it is also the logical choice since it should copy all numbers from index `num` up to the end of the array.

Comment: can you make a fixed for?